# Bootstrap custom JavaScript file not loading (Rails 4)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

> **SOLVED: See my answer below**

My ultimate goal is to build a Heroku-dashboard style collapsible sidebar (shrink heroku down to about 768px and it appears) in my application. However, I fail every time. Im using rails 4 and Bootstrap 3, which doesn't seem to have the inate ability to do something like this out of the box.

What exactly is going wrong with my rails app? I'm unable to load anything requiring JS on here. I've tried wrapping my JS in a `document.ready` but that hasn't worked either.

I've been following this [admittedly old, not that well written] guide:
http://seegatesite.com/create-simple-cool-sidebar-menu-with-bootstrap-3/

I've got `gem 'jquery-rails` in my `Gemfile`, and have the following in my `config/initializers/assets.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( app.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( app.css )
```

I've even tried inserting the required JS into a `<script> inside the`.html.erb` file to no avail. Any clues or helpful links for me?

It appears as though all the HTML and CSS is working perfectly fine, but the toggle button has no functionality.

**Here is my `app.js`:**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
//= require highcharts/highstock
//= require highcharts/highcharts
//= require highcharts/highcharts-more
//= require highcharts/modules/exporting

/* off-canvas sidebar toggle */

$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
     $("#menu-toggle-2").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled-2");
        $('#menu ul').hide();
    });

     function initMenu() {
      $('#menu ul').hide();
      $('#menu ul').children('.current').parent().show();
      //$('#menu ul:first').show();
      $('#menu li a').click(
        function() {
          var checkElement = $(this).next();
          if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            return false;
            }
          if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $('#menu ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
            checkElement.slideDown('normal');
            return false;
            }
          }
        );
      }
    $(document).ready(function() {initMenu();});
```

**My `app.css.scss`:**

```
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Simple Sidebar HTML Template (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

/* Toggle Styles */
/* This sidebar modified by seegatesite.com */

/*
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";


#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0; /* disini agar ketika di kecilkan tidak hilang semua default 0*/
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -250px;
}
.fixed-brand{
    width: auto;
}
/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 15px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    border-left: red 2px solid;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}
.no-margin{
    margin:0;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 250px;
    }
    .fixed-brand{
    width: 250px;
}
    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }
    #wrapper.toggled-2 #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 50px;
    }
    #wrapper.toggled-2 #sidebar-wrapper:hover {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
         -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
        padding-left: 250px;

    }
        #wrapper.toggled-2 #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-left: -200px;
         -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
}
```

**And lastly my `app.html.erb`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'app', media: 'all' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'app' %>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default no-margin">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header fixed-brand">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"  id="menu-toggle">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-rocket fa-4"></i> SEEGATESITE</a>
                </div><!-- navbar-header-->

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li class="active" ><button class="navbar-toggle collapse in" data-toggle="collapse" id="menu-toggle-2"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></li>
                            </ul>
                </div><!-- bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 -->
    </nav>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="menu">

                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-stack-1x "></i></span> Dashboard</a>
                       <ul class="nav-pills nav-stacked" style="list-style-type:none;">
                        <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-flag fa-stack-1x "></i></span> Shortcut</a>
                    <ul class="nav-pills nav-stacked" style="list-style-type:none;">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-flag fa-stack-1x "></i></span>link1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-flag fa-stack-1x "></i></span>link2</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-cloud-download fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Overview</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"> <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Events</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-stack-1x "></i></span>About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-server fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1>Simple Sidebar With Bootstrap 3 by Seegatesite.com</h1>
                        <p>This sidebar is adopted from <a href="http://startbootstrap.com/">start bootstrap simple sidebar</a>, which I modified slightly to be more cool. For tutorials and how to create it , you can read from my site </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Was fixed by moving the JavaScript file references to the bottom of the page. Will change question title to be more easily found by people this may help.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'app', media: 'all' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'app' %>
```